# OSX: Obj-C: how to get user last login and logout time of the user?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I need to fetch the last login and logout time of the user using objective-c. Is it possible?

I am able to see the whole record manually by viewing the following file

```
/private/var/log/accountpolicy.log
```

Even if I read the file from code and parse it but there are chances that user does not have the permission to access the file and so the app.

P.S: Can not ask user for right elevation window as I am doing it in background proecess.

Comment: I assume you mean under OSX?

Comment: Yes, OSX 10.5 @Droppy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `last` command.

https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=last&sektion=1

> LAST(1)           FreeBSD General Commands Manual            LAST(1)
>
> NAME
>        last -- indicate last logins of users and ttys
>
> SYNOPSIS
>        last [-swy] [-d [[CC]YY][MMDD]hhmm[.SS]] [-f file]   [-h host] [-n maxrec]     [-t tty] [user ...]

ex:

```
$ last
gbuzogany  ttys001                   Fri Mar 18 11:21 - 11:27  (00:06)
gbuzogany  ttys003                   Fri Mar 18 10:24 - 11:18  (00:54)
gbuzogany  ttys003                   Fri Mar 18 10:07 - 10:07  (00:00)
gbuzogany  ttys002                   Fri Mar 18 10:03 - 11:18  (01:15)
gbuzogany  ttys001                   Fri Mar 18 10:01 - 10:30  (00:29)
gbuzogany  ttys001                   Fri Mar 18 09:31 - 09:33  (00:01)
gbuzogany  ttys004                   Thu Mar 17 15:34 - 15:52  (00:18)
...
```

Comment: Sir, Thanks a lot for the command. It has almost solved my problem. Does it  work with standard users?? also is it possible to get `logout` time as well. Pardon me for my ignorance.

Comment: `SYNOPSIS last [-swy] [-d [[CC]YY][MMDD]hhmm[.SS]] [-f file] [-h host] [-n maxrec] [-t tty] [user ...]` the command you have provided is returning `wtmp begins Wed Feb 10 18:57` which is a wrong DateTime stamp :(

Comment: I don't understand. Are you having trouble parsing the output?

Comment: Yes Sir, actually tried to get the very last login fo a particular user stamp by running the terminal command :)

Comment: Check out `strptime`.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/strptime.3.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/strptime